# AutoHotKey how to pass/evaluate parameters to functions

Tags: autohotkey, parameters

I'm having trouble understanding how parameters are accessed in AutoHotKey functions.

For example, I set myVar variable with the InputBox, then pass it to a function. How do I evaluate the arg in the TestFunction?

```ahk
#t::
    inputbox myVar, What is your variable?
    myNewVar := TestFunction(%myVar%)
    MsgBox %myNewVar% 
    return

TestFunction(arg)
{
    MsgBox arg
    msgBox %arg%
    return %arg%
}
```

What I'm looking to do is setup a hotkey that will prompt for a keyword for an app, then evaluate what is entered in the function and fire up whatever app corresponds to that keyword.

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: When you call the function, you don't need percent signs around the parameter: `myNewVar := TestFunction(myVar)`

Comment: Bavi is right (he should have put his answer in an Answer): parameters called by a function need `function("string")` if they are strings, and just `function(variable)` (no percentage signs) if they are variables. It works if you just remove the percentage signs in your third line. I know how incredibly frustrating percentage signs and quotation marks can be in AHK: they kill me too from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

I've corrected your script (like Bavi_H suggested) and added an example to launch an application corresponding to a keyword.

```ahk
#t::
inputbox myVar, What is your variable?
myNewVar := TestFunction(myVar)
MsgBox %myNewVar% 
return

TestFunction(arg)
{
    msgBox %arg%
    if (arg = "calc")
    {
        run, calc.exe
    }
    else if (arg = "word")
    {
        run, winword.exe
    }
    return arg . "bob"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically commands, such as `run, %something%`, are different from functions, such as `myFunction(something)`.  Here is another example based on qwertzguy's answer

```ahk
#t::
    ; get variable from message box
    inputbox myVar, What is your variable?

    ; myVar DOES NOT have percents when passed to function
    myNewVar := TestFunction(myVar)

    ; myNewVar DOES have percents when passed to command
    MsgBox %myNewVar% 

return


TestFunction(arg)
{
    ; command DOES have percents 
    MsgBox Launching: %arg%

    if (arg = "calc")
    {
        ; commands use traditional variable method
        ; traditional method example: Var = The color is %FoundColor%
        ; variables are evaluated inside quotes

        run, "%A_WinDir%\system32\calc.exe"
    }
    else if (arg = "word")
    {

        ; functions need to use expression version since percents are not evaluated
        ; expression method example: Var := "The color is " . FoundColor
        ; variables are not evaluated inside quotes

        EnvGet, ProgramFilesVar, ProgramFiles(x86)
        OfficeVersionVar := "15"

        RunFunction(ProgramFilesVar . "\Microsoft Office\Office" . OfficeVersionVar . "\WINWORD.EXE")

    }

    return "You typed: " . arg

}



RunFunction(arg)
{
    run, %arg%
}
```